# How to overwrite a downloaded zip file

Tags: vb.net

I get a partial answer from one of your previous questions and answers(with an error) but not complete. The My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URi, destination filename, , , , , ) MSDN says that the next to last parameter is the timeout parameter, 1000 ms default, i.e., one second and then the last parameter is to indicate overwrite True or False. However there is no indication that you can use some parameter somewhere to overwrite the destination file. How can this be done?

Comment: Um... What do you think *overwrite (True or False)* means?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the file existence before you execute the download.

```
If File.Exists("my_zip_file_location") Then
     'delete the file'
     File.Delete("my_zip_file_location")
     'Download it again' 
     My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("your_new_zip_file_location")
  End If
```